# Apache POI - Write on the beginning of a merged area

Tags: java, merge, apache-poi

I am using Apache poi to merge an area on my excel sheet. I merge the cells E3:M6 and then I try to write on this area a sentence. So, i use setCellValue method of apache poi and I write on E3. But instead, my text is written on M3. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Without a single line of code it is hard to help.

Comment: Are you sure it's going in M3 not E3? Could the text just be right-aligned?

Answer (score -1):

I found out what the problem was. The default vertical aligment was bottom, but should be top alignment. Now it appears to be correct. Thanks for your time everyone